# Complete if statemet

Tags: javascript, arrays, if-statement, slice

In order to check my JS level, I was given such a task recently:

```
var array1 = [20, 50, 12, 1, 2],
    array2 = [];
for(var i = 0, length = array1.length; i < length; i++) {
    if(array1[i] === 12){
     // Complete if statement to make array2 equal to [20, 50, 1, 2]
      };
     array2.push(array1[i]);
}
```

My answer was:"It's impossible". Because variant ONE:

```
var array1 = [20, 50, 12, 1, 2],
    array2 = [];
for(var i = 0, length = array1.length; i < length; i++) {
    if(array1[i] === 12){
     array1 = [...array1.slice(0,i),  ...array1.slice(i+1)];
      };
     array2.push(array1[i]);
}
console.log(array2); // [20, 50, 1, 2, undefined]
```

attaches undefined.
Out of curiosity, I tried variant TWO:

```
var array1 = [20, 50, 12, 1, 2],
    array2 = [];
for(var i = 0, length = array1.length; i < length; i++) {
    if(array1[i] === 12){
     array1 = [...array1.slice(0,i),  ...array1.slice(i+1)];
     };
     array2.push(array1);
}
console.log(array2); //[[20, 50, 12, 1, 2], [circular object Array], [20, 50, 1, 2], [circular object Array], [circular object Array]]
```

Which turned to be even worse.
As for me, the ideal solution would be THREE:

```
var array1 = [20, 50, 12, 1, 2],
    array2 = [];
for(var i = 0, length = array1.length; i < length; i++) {
    if(array1[i] === 12){
     array2 = [...array1.slice(0,i),  ...array1.slice(i+1)];
     };
    }
console.log(array2); // [20, 50, 1, 2]
```

But it's not allowed.
So, my questions are:
1) Could it be solved as exactly as asked?
2) Why undefined shows up in variant ONE?
3) Why variant TWO is so verbose?

Comment: Or simply replace `// Complete if statement to make array2 equal to [20, 50, 1, 2]` with `continue;`

Comment: Or even simpler, replace it with `i++`.